# How to replace space in uri with Isapi rewrite

Tags: replace, char, isapi-rewrite

i have to replace spaces in uri like :
 /parma/vendita/villa%20schiera/via%20cremonese/

With a - char to have this:
/parma/vendita/villa-schiera/via-cremonese/10339

I really appreciate a suggestion to write isapi rewrite rule

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%20(.*)$ /$1-$2 [NC,LP]
```